# react.js every nth item add opening tag or closing tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, jsx

I'm having trouble with this logic since react/jsx does not allow for non closing tags to be added to an array/child component. For example with bootstrap css I want to add a row for **every** 4 columns.

So the logic is as follows:

Add a opening row ex: `<div className="row">`, then loop inside this row and every loop append a column ex: `<div className="column>{this.data}</div>` when the loop reaches 4 check with `if(i % 4 == 0)` and add a closing `</div>` tag while adding new row tag `<div className="row">`;

The code below ***would*** work in another language but in react this is not doable since we push a closing tag and a opening tag (which is invalid jsx):

```
generateColumns(columns) {
 let newColumns = [];

 columns.forEach(function(column, idx) {
  newColumns.push( <div className="column"> some data </div> );

  if (idx % 4 == 0) {
   // Here we end the row and start a new row, works in any other language.
   newColumns.push( </div> <div className="row"> );
  }
 });

 // This array now has the proper tags for opening a row every 4th item and closing it.
 return newColumns;
},
render() {
   return (
     <div className="row">
       {this.generateColumns(this.props.columns)}
     </div>
   )
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
   Some data
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   Some more data
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   Other data
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   Something else
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
   Some data
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   Some more data
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   Other data
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   Something else
  </div>
</div>
```

`//the above would be repeated and new rows would appear every 4 columns.`

Comment: > works in any other language

JSX is not a string concatenating language. It will be transpiled to actual JS code so your code won't work

Comment: I know, so what is the right way to handle this logic with React / JSX?

Comment: Can you update your question with the HTML markup you want to produce?

Comment: Updated @NguyễnĐăngKhoa

Comment: Rows should be a component with column components.

Comment: You split your array into chunk of 4 and do what @DaveNewton said

Comment: Heh, easier said than done - haven't seen an example of this yet.

Comment: So there is only one row of data with many columns ?

Comment: @AntonB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks; the React part is trivial once you have massaged the data appropriately.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
render() {
   const rows = array_chunk(this.props.columns, 4)
   return (
     {
       rows.map((row) => (
         <div className="row">
         {
           row.map((col) => (
             <div className="col">{ col }</div>
           ))
         }
         </div>
       ))
     }
   )
}
```

An example array_chunk (I recommend that you use lodash)

```
module.exports = function chunks(arr, size) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    throw new TypeError('Input should be Array');
  }

  if (typeof size !== 'number') {
    throw new TypeError('Size should be a Number');
  }

  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
    result.push(arr.slice(i, size + i));
  }

  return result;
};
```

Comment: How does this handle 9 columns? if size is 2 (2 chunks of 4) you would lose the 9th item...

Comment: It will create the first row with 4 cols and the second row with 3 cols. That's how array_chunk work.

Comment: @AntonB mapping twice is O(2n) == O(n); mapping a complete set for each n would be O(n^2)

Comment: Maybe. But from my experience with React.js. This is the only way to solve this.

Comment: @Mathletics good point, I stand corrected - thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 4):

I actually just used arrays and react handled fine the rendering.

```
render() {
    let rows = [],
        cols = []
    let index = 0
    const totalCols = 20;

    for (index; index < totalCols; index++) {
        cols.push(<div class="col" key={index}/>)
        if ((index + 1) % 4 == 0) {
            rows.push(
                <div class="row" key={index}>
                    {cols}
                </div>
            )
            cols = []
        }
    }
    return (
        <div class="container">
            {rows}
        </div>
    )
}
```