# render DIV in react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**hi. a task :**

I get an array with posts from the server. And return it:

```
{ this.state.articles.map((article) => {
return ( <div className={css(styles.feed_row)}>
  <div key={article.id} className={ css(boxes.art_box) }>
    <span className={css(boxes.cover)}>
      <img  src={article.art_cover} alt="" width={350}/>
    </span>
  </div>
</div> )
}
```

on the way out I will get one div with many posts.

**But** how to limit each **.feed_row**, only two elements or, having reached the maximum width, automatically create a new **.feed_row** and continue adding posts to it?

**I'm trying to get something like this:**

[image]

Comment: You can insert line breaks(kinda complicated), or set the `<div>`s to `display: inline-block;` so they are next to each other as long as there's enough space, then wrap around.

Comment: I do not need a style, but a render function. the number of posts may be different

Comment: Are you asking how to have multiple divs per row?

Comment: max-width of each parent is 750, max-width of child can be different. the widest is also 750

Comment: how to place no more than two per row))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react.js every nth item add opening tag or closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318601/react-js-every-nth-item-add-opening-tag-or-closing-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to turn a one-dimensional array into the required two dimensional one:

```js
function articleRows(articles, max, maxWidth) {
  var rows = [];
  var currentRow = [];
  const fits = a => currentRow.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.width, 0) + a.width <= maxWidth;
  articles.forEach(a => {
    if (currentRow.length < max && fits(a)) return currentRow.push(a);
    rows.push(currentRow);
    currentRow = [a];
  });
  rows.push(currentRow);
  return rows;
}

var articles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  articles.push({
    width: Math.ceil(Math.random() * Math.random() * 4) * 150 + 150
  });
}

var rows = articleRows(articles, 2, 750);

console.log(articles.map(a => a.width));
console.log(rows.map(row => row.map(a => a.width).join(", ")));
```

The basic idea is to create an empty row array, push to it as long as suitable, then move on to the next row.

Here's a React sandbox showcasing the final result: https://codesandbox.io/s/pmopkvwkq7

Comment: Yes, it seems it works. But there is still a question. You have a width initially set. At me - style is appropriated proceeding from type of a post, and it in percentage. What to do?