# Convert string of co-ordinates to nested objects x and y

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:
`area = "73,159,160,178,165,340,70,382"`;
And I need to convert it to the following format:

```
area = [
{
"x": 73,
"y": 159,
},
{
"x": 160,
"y": 178,
},
{
"x": 165,
"y": 340,
},
{
"x": 70,
"y": 382,
}
]
```

I can start by converting it to a normal array:

```
JSON.parse("[" + area + "]")
```

But I'm now stuck on how to make the nested objects. How would I now know what is every other odd and even number and allocate it to the corresponding object?

Comment: You may try with `reduce` method. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62880863/7808889) would be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string by a comma and use a `for` loop to loop through the resulting array and construct the objects:

```js
const str = "73,159,160,178,165,340,70,382"

const split = str.split(",")
const arr = []

for(let i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
  arr.push({"x":split[i], "y":split[++i]})
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: That's amazingly short quick code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve? please note that I didn't add a code to check if the number of item In the array will be even or not, so if your newArea is odd this function will fail

```js
function Convert(arrayOfArea){
    let Converted = [];
  let count = arrayOfArea.length/2;
  let mod = arrayOfArea.length%2;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
    Converted.push({x:0 , y:0});
    Converted[i].x = arrayOfArea[i]
    Converted[i].y = arrayOfArea[i+1];
  }
  return Converted;
}

let strArea = "73,159,160,178,165,340,70,382";
let newArea = JSON.parse("["+strArea+"]");
console.log(Convert(newArea));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of approaching this using `String.split()` and `Array.reduce()`.

We use String.split to split the area string into an array, then use reduce to turn into the desired result. The + shorthand is simply converting the string coordinates to numbers.

```js
const area = "73,159,160,178,165,340,70,382";
const result = area.split(',').reduce((acc, s, i, a) => [...acc, ...((i % 2) ? [{ x: +a[i-1], y: +s}] : []) ], []);
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using regex

```js
let area = "73,159,160,178,165,340,70,382"

let regex = /\d+,\d+/g

match = area.match(regex).map(match => {
  let [x, y] = match.split(",")
  return {x, y}
})

console.log(match)
```